# phpexcel - add new row in existing excel file using phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

All data in array like this

```
<?php
$sub_arr = array();  
$sub_arr[] = array(
    'sr_nm' => 1,
    'recept_number' => 3019,
    'adm_number' => 3434,
    'student_name' => 'amit',
    'class' => 'LKG',
    'pay' => 'online',
    'cheq_nm' => '',
    'adm_fee' => '',
    'consolidated' => '',
    'sec.fee' => '',
    'dev.charge' => 5000,
    'school_fee' => 1300,
    'subling' => '-3400',
    'transport' => 2300,
    'late_fee' =>'total' => 35006
);
$sub_arr[] = array('sr_nm' => 1,
    'recept_number' => 3019,
    'adm_number' => 3434,
    'student_name' => 'amit',
    'class' => 'LKG',
    'pay' => 'online',
    'cheq_nm' => '',
    'adm_fee' => '',
    'consolidated' => '',
    'sec.fee' => '',
    'dev.charge' => 5000,
    'school_fee' => 1300,
    'subling' => '-3400',
    'transport' => 2300,
    'late_fee' => '',
    'total' => 35006
);
```

And my excel file:

[image: see excel file screen shoot]

I want to insert new data from A4 shell after loading the file.

Comment: Fyi: PhpExcel is deprecated

Comment: And what have you tried so far?